# OCX/ActiveX dll function is not callable in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, ocx

I have one OCX control installed it my machine using regsvr32 command. Then I have added the object tag,

```
<object classid="clsid:GUID"
```

Now, I am calling the global function of OCX from the machine which is working. Then I tested the same on another machine it doesn't work. In short, it works someplace and someplace it doesn't. I have enabled ActiveX on all machines.

Am I missing something that the same OCS works in one machine and doesn't work in other machines?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? Is there any error when the function not working? First I think you need to check if the dll is registered sucessfully. You can refer to the method in [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/576831/how-do-i-know-if-a-dll-is-registered). If the dll is indeed registered, please check the ActiveX settings in IE and  enable the settings according to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-activex-controls-for-internet-explorer-11-25738d05-d357-39b4-eb2f-fdd074bbf347). Besides, you can also try to add your site to Trusted sites list.

Comment: @YuZhou Thanks, Actually I know the GUID and I ran this command `reg query HKCR\CLSID | find /i "{9F3DBFEE-FD77-4774-868B-65F75E7DB7C3}"` and it returns nothing but it works on my machine

Comment: If you can confirm that it works fine in your machine, you can try to compare the ActiveX related settings between the working machines and the not working machines.  Besides, you can also compare the IE versions between the working one and not working one. It can help to narrow down the issue. Please also try to add your site to Trusted sites list to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @YuZhou actually there was missing sensor driver were missing. Your link was very helpful though.

Comment: Sounds like you have solved the issue. You can also put the solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @YuZhou I have added an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, ActiveX was enabled (as per the article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-activex-controls-for-internet-explorer-11-25738d05-d357-39b4-eb2f-fdd074bbf347 thanks Yu Zhou). My OCX control was dependent upon a fingerprint device driver. When I installed the missing dependencies it works perfectly. http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and OleView are helpers to find the missing dependencies